# Number of covers of $[n]$ by exactly $m$ distinct sets of size $k$

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to compute the number of ways how to arrange sets $A_1, \dots, A_m \subseteq [n]$ such that

- $|A_i| = k$,
- $A_i$ and $A_j$ are distinct,
- $\bigcup A_i = [n]$.

I tried to set up some recursions (i.e. how the value changes for $m+1$), but seems to be quite tedious.
I think that perhaps these values might be known to experts and I would be very grateful for some reference.
Thank you.

Comment: **Hint:** First, count the number of ways to choose $m$ distinct sets with size $k$. Then, use the principle of inclusion-exclusion to subtract the “bad” ways where some element is missing from the union, then add back in the doubly bad ways where two elements are missing, etc.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you. I should have thought of this usual trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=k\cdot m$. Choosing a partition into $m$ sets of size $k$ is like choosing, for each $x \in [n]$, what is the unique set $A_i$ in which it resides, s.t. every $A_i$ is of size $k$. For the first set, $A_1$, there are $n \choose k$ ways to choose its $k$ elements. There are now $n-k$ elements left, and ${n-k} \choose k$ ways to choose the elements of $A_2$. Continuing in the same fashion, we have

$${n \choose k} \cdot {n-k \choose k}\cdot {n-2k \choose k} \cdots {k\choose k}={n \choose k, k,\ldots, k}$$

ways to choose such partitions, where the RHS is a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

We can also view such a partition as a function $f:[n]\to [m]$ which obtains each value exactly $k$ times, or, equivalently, as ways of distributing $n$ distinct balls into $m$ distinct boxes, each box having exactly $k$ balls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I should have been more explicit that I am truly looking for the number of covers, i.e. I only assume $n \leq m \cdot k$, but not necessarily an equality. Nevertheless, I think I will be able to compute the values using the hint from the Mike Earnest's comment.